# ActiveStorage intermittently returning "Couldn't find ActiveStorage::Blob with 'id'"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, rails-activestorage

I have a simple controller spec, which is supposed to check the processing for a new Material is queued when the item is created.

materials_controller_spec.rb (#create):

```
  it 'queues the processing of the material' do
    post :create, params: { material: valid_attributes }, session: valid_session

    expect(ProcessMaterialJob).to(
      have_been_enqueued.with(material_id: Material.last.id, video_filepath: Material.last.video_filepath)
    )
  end
```

When run in isolation it's fine, but when I run the whole suite with `rspec .` I get the following error:

```
 ActiveJob::DeserializationError:
   Error while trying to deserialize arguments: Couldn't find ActiveStorage::Blob with 'id'=418
 # ./spec/controllers/materials_controller_spec.rb:81:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ------------------
 # --- Caused by: ---
 # ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
 #   Couldn't find ActiveStorage::Blob with 'id'=418
 #   ./spec/controllers/materials_controller_spec.rb:81:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

There have been a couple of points where I've not been convinced the attachment has been fully uploaded before the next page has rendered. I am concerned this could mean an issue with the file uploads. I followed the guide on [direct uploads](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads) but I still see no progress indicator when uploading the video files, which are quite large.

My questions are:

1. What is causing the strange `Couldn't find ActiveStorage::Blob
   with 'id'=418` issue?
2. How can I debug the file upload if that's where the issue is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you handling database cleaning between tests? Are you running parallel tests on the same dataset? This could be from the database being cleaned while the tests are running.

Comment: I've not configured any parallel tests (additional gems are required to get rspec to do this) and `use_transactional_fixtures = true`. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that there are additional Gems required to set up parallel testing. But since you didn't supply your Gemfile, how should I have known you hadn't? 

If you feel annoyed by me trying to help, I will make a note of avoiding to do so in the future.

Comment: Hi @EmilKampp, not sure why you thought I was criticising you, I certainly didn't mean to. Perhaps I was a bit matter-of-fact, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd previously added `ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test` to my `rails_helper.rb` so it should have worked. However, adding that line into the particular test seemed to resolve the issue.

```
it 'queues the processing of the material' do
  post :create, params: { material: valid_attributes }, session: valid_session

  expect(ProcessMaterialJob).to(
    have_been_enqueued.with(material_id: Material.last.id, video_filepath: Material.last.video_filepath)
  )
end
```